# Creating a HIVE table that filters data from a .csv in HDFS based on the value in a column

Tags: csv, hive, hdfs, hiveql, avro

I currently have a file which contains data in it that needs to populate 9 different tables. Each of these tables has a different number of columns and datatypes, therefore I need to filter the source file (using the first column which determines which table the row will go into).

My current method is to create a table that has generic columns names col_1, col_2 etc up to the last filled column in the file and then create 9 views that reference this file. The issue I have is that there are a different data types appearing in the same columns due to the fact the tables are all different structures.

Is there a possibility to create a dynamic schema that filters the .csv that the HIVE table points to base on the first column??

thanks

Comment: Please add a data sample

Answer (score 2):

#### Demo

**data.csv**

```
1,1,Now,11,22,2016-12-12
1,2,I,33,44,2017-01-01
3,3,heard,55,66,2017-02-02
1,4,you,77,88,2017-03-03
2,5,know,99,1010,2017-04-04
1,6,that,1111,1212,2017-05-05
2,7,secret,1313,1414,2017-06-06
```

---

```
create external table mycsv
(
    rec_type    int
   ,id          int
   ,mystring    string
   ,myint1      int
   ,myint2      int
   ,mydate      date
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from mycsv;

+----------+----+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| rec_type | id | mystring | myint1 | myint2 |   mydate   |
+----------+----+----------+--------+--------+------------+
|        1 |  1 | Now      | 11     | 22     | 2016-12-12 |
|        1 |  2 | I        | 33     | 44     | 2017-01-01 |
|        3 |  3 | heard    | 55     | 66     | 2017-02-02 |
|        1 |  4 | you      | 77     | 88     | 2017-03-03 |
|        2 |  5 | know     | 99     | 1010   | 2017-04-04 |
|        1 |  6 | that     | 1111   | 1212   | 2017-05-05 |
|        2 |  7 | secret   | 1313   | 1414   | 2017-06-06 |
+----------+----+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

---

```
create table t1(id int,mystring string);
create table t2(id int,mystring string,mydate date);
create table t3(id int,mydate date,myint1 int,myint2 int);
```

---

```
from mycsv 
insert into t1 select id,mystring               where rec_type = 1
insert into t2 select id,mystring,mydate        where rec_type = 2
insert into t3 select id,mydate,myint1,myint2   where rec_type = 3
```

---

```
select * from t1;

+----+----------+
| id | mystring |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Now      |
|  2 | I        |
|  4 | you      |
|  6 | that     |
+----+----------+
```

---

```
select * from t2;

+----+----------+------------+
| id | mystring |   mydate   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  5 | know     | 2017-04-04 |
|  7 | secret   | 2017-06-06 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

---

```
select * from t3;

+----+------------+--------+--------+
| id |   mydate   | myint1 | myint2 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
|  3 | 2017-02-02 |     55 |     66 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi Dudu, thank-you for your response I had a feeling this would be the only option. In order to automate this would the best method be to create a UDF that runs in apache PIG?  Ideally the user file provider just needs to drop the file in the HDFS file store and it be visable straight away in HIVE tables..

Comment: This (`from` + multiple `insert`) seems like a clean solution. For what reason do you find it irrelevant?